# PSQL error ambigous column name when doing multi join statment

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to solve somehow the error in my PSQL query of `ambiguous origin_type column name`

The query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "message"
    INNER JOIN "member" ON "member"."id" = "message"."member_id"
    INNER JOIN "conversation" ON "conversation"."id" = "message"."conversation_id"
WHERE
    "message_type" in('USER_MESSAGE')
    AND "origin_type" in('CONSENTEE_RECIPIENT')
    AND "origin_type" in('CONSENTEE')
```

I have 2 columns with the same name and need a way to avoid this error but as I'm not practical at this point I'm blocked as don't know the better way of fixing this.

I tried to use aliases without success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `"member"."origin_type"` or `"conversation"."origin_type"` or `"message"."origin_type"` instead of just `"origin_type"` depending on which table's `origin_type` you need.